# Agricultural self sufficiency after yellowstone eruption?

Tags: volcanology, homework, agriculture

Given a 440 acre farm running roughly 200 acres of Crops and 40-50 head of cattle,in the secondary ash zone within the lake of the ozarks reigon of Missouri, how viable would survival be relying on self sufficiency for a family of 4? How would agriculture be able to recover in this reigon? How badly would agriculture be harmed? Absolutely useless or a just a severe cut to food yeild? And how would it be possible to survive all the dust in the air? Also, affects to grazing land and crop land, what would they be, and what methods could be used to recover?

Comment: This is one of those awkward questions that's a bit interdisciplinary for Stackexchange. You need info on likely amounts of ash, sunlight, etc., from people here, but then the rest of the question becomes one about farming.